# Magento 2.3 | Knockout.js - Unexpected end of input

Tags: knockoutjs, magento2.3

I've installed the latest Magento Version (2.3) and everythign went well. The installation was completed and i was able to view and frontend aswell the backend.

For some reason i get the following error on the backend and the loading spinner keeps spinning forever. Sometimes, after a refresh, the spinner goes away but no menu items are clickable. In the Chrome DevTools i get various of errors displayed, especially with knockout.js or knockout related files.

**PHP Version:** 7.2
**Magento Version:** 2.3

---

**Knockout.js:4566**
*Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input*
https://pastebin.com/2XGmf8Qm

---

**knockout-fast-foreach.js:299**
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindingHandlers' of undefined*
https://pastebin.com/hTLK677z

---

**mage-init.js:13**
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindingHandlers' of undefined*
https://pastebin.com/wEGi6yfm

---

**fadeVisible.js:12**
*Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'bindingHandlers' of undefined*
https://pastebin.com/aG3GAWs5

---

**i18n.js:151**
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindingHandlers' of undefined*
https://pastebin.com/jFHtb83z

---

**optgroup.js:19**
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindingHandlers' of undefined*
https://pastebin.com/4E9BtNZv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed.
I've downloaded the `knockout.js` manually from the github Repo and replaced it with mine.
Everything works now as expected. Seems like there was something going wrong while transfering the data.

Comment: Please provide the link for magento 2.3.4 version and also the path of file where we need to replace it